# WireMock: Temp disable stub response

Tags: wiremock

I use **WireMock** to stub responses from remote server.
In folder `wiremock/mappings` I have many files that set rules for stub.
Here example:

{

```
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/merchant"
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 3000,
    "bodyFileName": "stub_response.json"
  }
}
```

As you can see, when I get request `/merchant` then return stubbed response from file  `stub_response.json`.
Nice. It's work fine.

But suppose I need temporary to disable this response. Is it possible to turn off stub response and return real response from remote server?

I need flag like this :  `"disable" : true`

Is it possible in WireMock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable a rule by using the WireMock admin interface.  If you invoke a DELETE command against `http://.../__admin/mappings/<guid>`, then the mapping will be deleted.

You can get a list of all the guids by performing a GET command against `http://.../__admin/`

If you want to replace a mapping with a real response instead of a stubbed response, you can add a second mapping that has a lower priority than the stubbed response and that proxies through to the real address.  Normally, your stubbed response ill be used, but when you then delete the stubbed response, Wiremock will proxy through to the real address as it will then become the highest priority mapping.

To add a proxy, add the following into the response mapping

`"proxyBaseUrl" : "http://otherhost.com",`

To set the priority of mappings, add the following into your mapping JSON.

`"priority": 1,`

Comment: Yes, it's help, but it's too complex.

Answer (score 0):

There presently isn't a disable attribute to a rule. You can remove a wiremock rule and re-add it later, which would functionally be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you running Wiremock as a [*Stand-alone* process](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/), you can set it into [recording mode](http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/), effectively this will proxy all requests to a target URL.

Open http://localhost:8080/__admin/recorder (assuming you started WireMock on the default port of 8080), on that screen you have to enter the target URL and click the "Record" button. Until you stop recording it will make this Wiremock acting as a proxy.

If the recording is not something you actually need, you can dismiss recorded stub mappings. Although this is slightly misusing the *Recorder* feature it is a fast and easy way to temporarily turn your Wiremock into a proxy, instead of responding with stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Wiremock can select which fixture to use depending on in which [state of a scenario](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) it runs. In different states, even for same request, it can have different mappings thus behave in different ways (in one of the states can respond from a fixture, and in another state it can be forwarded to the real API).

Say if there is a *Proxy* scenario, which is currently in the default *Started* state, then all the queries will be served by stubs that are not specific to any scenario state.

But if the *Proxy* scenario is in *Active* state, and we have a mapping that is specific for that scenario state (*requiredScenarioState* property), and it has a higher priority than default, then this mapping will be executed for any URI to this Wiremock instance:

```
{
    "scenarioName": "Proxy",
    "requiredScenarioState": "Activated",
    "priority": 2,
    "request": {
        "urlPattern": ".*"
    },
    "response": {
        "proxyBaseUrl": "https://swapi.dev/api"
    }
}
```

The value for *response.proxyBaseUrl*, will make all the requests to be forwarded to provided host, when this mapping is matched.

Now we need to be able to toggle *Proxy* scenario to *Activated* state and back,
so we define two more mappings for `POST /proxy` endpoint on this Wiremock. They will have even higher *priority* - 1, so they can override even the mapping for `"urlPattern": ".*"`.

Drop a JSON file containing all three mappings to your `wiremock/mappings`:

```
{
    "mappings": [
        {
            "scenarioName": "Proxy",
            "requiredScenarioState": "Activated",
            "priority": 2,
            "request": {
                "urlPattern": ".*"
            },
            "response": {
                "proxyBaseUrl": "https://swapi.dev/api"
            }
        },
        {
            "priority": 1,
            "scenarioName": "Proxy",
            "requiredScenarioState": "Activated",
            "newScenarioState": "Started",
            "request": { "method": "POST", "url": "/proxy"},
            "response": { "status": 201, "body": "Proxy De-activated (Stubs will be used)" }
        },
        {
            "priority": 1,
            "scenarioName": "Proxy",
            "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
            "newScenarioState": "Activated",
            "request": { "method": "POST", "url": "/proxy" },
            "response": { "status": 201, "body": "Proxy Activated (Will forward all requests)" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you can switch the *Proxy* scenario to *Activated* state,
and after switch it back to *Started* state with:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/proxy -XPOST
```

Good thing about this approach that this mapping file can be copied from project to project with minimal changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid deleting rules by adding both rules with two different priorities. Then, when you want it to work the other way, use the ADMIN API and swap the priorities, by calling PUT on the rule to update the rule.

So, to begin with start with higher priority for stubbing, and lower priority for proxy rule. Then, when you want to avoid stubbing for some time, give the higher priority to the proxy rule and leave the stubbing rule with the existing priority.